# TextFSM logic - Avoid capturing same data twice

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to record optics light readings off a cisco RFGW.  The issue I'm facing is that because of the way the data is displayed I capture the Physical interface twice and the data I want appended after each entry.  I can of course fix it after I've collected the info but I'd like to avoid much data manipulation after parsing it the output.

Raw text:
   `HE-EQM-01#show interfaces transceiver detail | begin Transmit Power
               Transmit Power     Threshold   Threshold  Threshold  Threshold
    Port       (dBm)              (dBm)       (dBm)      (dBm)      (dBm)
    ---------  -----------------  ----------  ---------  ---------  ---------
    Te1/2       -3.0                 1.6        -1.3        -7.3      -11.3
    Te1/3      -17.3                 1.6        -1.3        -7.3      -11.3
    Te1/4      -40.0                 1.6        -1.3        -7.3      -11.3
    Te2/2       -3.1                 1.6        -1.3        -7.3      -11.3
    Te2/3      -40.0                 1.6        -1.3        -7.3      -11.3
    Te2/4      -40.0                 1.6        -1.3        -7.3      -11.3`

    `Optical            High Alarm  High Warn  Low Warn   Low Alarm
               Receive Power      Threshold   Threshold  Threshold  Threshold
    Port       (dBm)              (dBm)       (dBm)      (dBm)      (dBm)
    -------    -----------------  ----------  ---------  ---------  ---------
    Te1/2      -40.0                 1.9        -1.0        -9.9      -13.9
    Te1/3       -2.6                 1.9        -1.0        -9.9      -13.9
    Te1/4       -2.9                 1.9        -1.0        -9.9      -13.9
    Te2/2       -3.0                 1.9        -1.0        -9.9      -13.9
    Te2/3       -2.6                 1.9        -1.0        -9.9      -13.9`

Template:

```
Value interface (\w+\d\/\d+)
Value tx (-*\d+\.\d+)
Value rx (-*\d+\.\d+)

Start
  ^\s*Transmit\s*Power.+
  ^\s*${interface}\s+${tx} -> Record
```

Output:

```
[['Te1/2', '-3.0', ''],
['Te1/3', '-17.3', ''],
['Te1/4', '-40.0', ''],
['Te2/2', '-3.1', ''],
['Te2/3', '-40.0', ''],
['Te2/4', '-40.0', ''],
['Te1/2', '-40.0', ''],
['Te1/3', '-2.6', ''],
['Te1/4', '-2.9', ''],
['Te2/2', '-3.0', ''],
['Te2/3', '-2.6', ''],
['Te2/4', '-2.4', '']]
```

Preferably:

```
[['Te1/2', '-3.0', '-40.0'],
['Te1/3', '-17.3', '-2.6'],
['Te1/4', '-40.0', '-2.9'],
['Te2/2', '-3.1', '-3.0'],
['Te2/3', '-40.0', '-2.6'],
['Te2/4', '-40.0', '-2.4'],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decomposed a bit. What you want is:

1. Match the interface: `(\w+\d\/\d+)`
2. After a few spaces, match the transmit power: `(-?\d\.\d+)` (use of `?` is preferable here as you don't want multiple following `-`)
3. Find in the following text the same interface again: `(?=.*\1)`
4. That one followed by the received power (same as 2.)

If you assemble it all, you get:

```
(\w+\d+\/\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)(?=.+\1\s+(-?\d+\.\d+))
                                      ^
Capturing in the lookahead, that way relevant data is captured, but not eaten by the engine, which would prevent following matches.
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DY0Meb/1).